Convert between the spatial and Miller-Bravais representations
Story: I am postprocessing my atomistic simulation results done in Lammps by Ovito. One of the interesting features of Ovito is DXA (Dislocation Analysis), which gives information about the dislocations that are generated during the simulation. Interestingly, it can identify the Burgers vector of the dislocations.
Question: Ovito has identified one of the dislocations as follows:
Spatial Burgers vector: (0.0056,2.8195,1.4966)
Burgers vector in Bravais-Miller: 1/3 [-2 1 1 0]
I am wondering how this conversion between the the spatial and BM representations is done. I am working with magnesium and the HCP crystal is oriented such that the global x axis is aligned with the crystal's [0001] axis, the global y axis is aligned with the crystal's [-1010] axis, and the global z axis is aligned with the crystal's [1-210] axis.
